# How do you unbold subtotals in a Power BI matrix?

Tags: powerbi, themes

I would like to have my subtotals in my matrix in regular font, but the default is to have them in bold. I have read the documentation on JSON themes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-themes) but am still not able to get this right.

I have tried and am able to change sizes and fonts faces, but when it comes to the font face it always makes it bold regardless that I put a font face that is not bold - my single theme adjustment I am using for import is included below.

The documentation even references this issue exactly so it must be something rather simple I'm missing:

"... However, if you don’t like the inheritance rules (for example, if you don’t want your totals to be a bolded version of the values in a table), you can explicitly format the secondary classes in the theme file, just like you can format the primary classes..."

```
{
    "name": "Custom Theme",
    "textClasses": {
        "boldLabel": {
            "fontFace": "Segoe UI"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct solution for this. But a workaround is using some specific fonts with Light version to achieve the requirement. Please check the attached image.

[image]